# getJSON alert not returning anything - data issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson, slack-api

I am having issues reading this data:

It looks like this:

```
{
  "ok": true,
  "messages": [
    {
      "text": "moo",
      "username": "bot",
      "type": "message",
      "subtype": "bot_message",
      "ts": "1448226157.000008"
    },
    {
      "text": "boo",
      "username": "bot",
      "type": "message",
      "subtype": "bot_message",
      "ts": "1448225998.000007"
    }
  ],
  "has_more": true
}
```

Here's the code:

```
$.getJSON("https://slack.com/api/channels.history?token=xxxx&channel=C0E&pretty=1", function(result){
            $.each(result, function(i, field){
                $("div").append(field + " ");
            });
        });
```

All I get is

> [object object][object object]

How can I get the data to show properly?

Comment: I actually was getting the json from a url but thought it would be easier to add it directly into the variable, forgetting that I was breaking it. Let me change it.

Comment: Edited. Hope this makes more sense

Comment: please provide the real token, so we can test it better

Comment: have you tried to `console.log` your `result`?

Comment: With the object as-shown, I'd expect `true`, `[Object, Object]`, `true` -- the values for 'ok', 'messages' and 'has_more', respectively. Although, of course, they could be in any order. Remember that JS objects are unordered; don't assume they'll iterate in any particular order.

Comment: result is: true [object Object],[object Object],[object Object] etc

Comment: What exactly are you trying to show in the `<div>`? The message text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming:

1. That's the full JSON
2. You want to loop through the messages

Your loop should be more like:

```
$.each( result.messages,
  function( i, msg ) {
    $("div").append( msg.username + ": " + msg.text + " " );   
  }
);
```

(or whichever fields you wish to display)

Answer (score 2):

You mean something like this:

```js
var data = `{"ok": true,"messages": [
        {
            "text": "moo",
            "username": "bot",
            "type": "message",
            "subtype": "bot_message",
            "ts": "1448226157.000008"
        },
        {
            "text": "boo",
            "username": "bot",
            "type": "message",
            "subtype": "bot_message",
            "ts": "1448225998.000007"
        }
    ],
    "has_more": true
}`;

$(function() {
  var result = $.parseJSON(data);
  $.each(result, function(i, item) {
    if (typeof item != "object") {
      alert(item);
    } else {
      $.each(item, function(i, obj) {
        alert(obj.ts);
      });
    }

  });
});
```

#### Sample fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4v0x34b1/